# Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use

Tags: google-calendar-api

Please, can anyone let me know how much time will it take for verification as I need to verify for production also?

Answer (score 0):

Most verification requests receive a response within 24 to 72 hours. 
You can check the Verification status at the top of the OAuth consent screen form. 
When verification of your OAuth client is confirmed, your app is verified and also keep it in mind that Google will ignore your request for verification unless you have one or more sensitive scopes listed in the OAuth consent screen list of "Scopes for Google APIs".
Keep in mind that every time you edit your application restarts the verification process.

Comment: okay, thanks, I have mentioned my all scope while verifying, so is there anything I need to do for scope ?

as by default: email, profile, openid is there on OAuth consent screen form. but while verify I mentioned the used at client option.